# Integrate QuickBooks Desktop Application using Java without API

Tags: java, quickbooks

I am new to QuickBooks.

I want to create a Java Application which will communicate with QuickBooks desktop version to import and export data.

I have googled and found many articles and solutions but none of them worked for me.
For example below are few solutions which I have already tried.
https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/readme.html#QBWebConnectorSvc%20(Java)%20(qbxml)%20(desktop)
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK13_Samples
https://www.molecularbear.com/blog/using-the-quickbooks-sdk-via-jacob-java-com-bridge/

I have installed QBXML_SDK13 sdk but i have no idea how it will work. I tried to understand from above mentioned articles but didn't get any hint.
Also, followed the given steps but no luck.

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Please guide.

Thanks.